# panic: invalid page type: 2: 10 & page 5 already freed on Kubed Chronograf

Tags: influxdb, azure-aks, chronograf

I have influx v1.7.9 on Azure kubernetes service and I tried to add chronograf but failed to start, it has a PVC to store data using an azure storage account.

```
    panic: invalid page type: 2: 10

    goroutine 1 [running]:
    github.com/boltdb/bolt.(*Cursor).search(0xc000551960, 0x2f083e0, 0x5, 0x5, 0x2)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/boltdb/bolt@v0.0.0-20160719165138-5cc10bbbc5c1/cursor.go:256 +0x354
    github.com/boltdb/bolt.(*Cursor).seek(0xc000551960, 0x2f083e0, 0x5, 0x5, 0xc000b03640, 0x40d619, 0xc0000b92e8, 0x8, 0x8, 0x1417b00, ...)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/boltdb/bolt@v0.0.0-20160719165138-5cc10bbbc5c1/cursor.go:159 +0x7e
    github.com/boltdb/bolt.(*Bucket).Bucket(0xc000116478, 0x2f083e0, 0x5, 0x5, 0xc000b03718)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/boltdb/bolt@v0.0.0-20160719165138-5cc10bbbc5c1/bucket.go:112 +0xef
    github.com/boltdb/bolt.(*Tx).Bucket(...)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/boltdb/bolt@v0.0.0-20160719165138-5cc10bbbc5c1/tx.go:101
    github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt.(*BuildStore).get(0xc0000b9188, 0x207e0e0, 0xc0000b4010, 0xc000116460, 0xc00000cea0, 0xc000b03748, 0x42da8f, 0xc000000008, 0xc0000bc040, 0x0)
        /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt/build.go:66 +0x77
    github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt.(*BuildStore).Get.func1(0xc000116460, 0x1ed3cb8, 0xc000116460)
        /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt/build.go:30 +0x53
    github.com/boltdb/bolt.(*DB).View(0xc00000cd20, 0xc000b037e8, 0x0, 0x0)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/boltdb/bolt@v0.0.0-20160719165138-5cc10bbbc5c1/db.go:626 +0x90
    github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt.(*BuildStore).Get(0xc0000b9188, 0x207e0e0, 0xc0000b4010, 0xc00047ba00, 0xc000b03880, 0x4d293d, 0xc0000462aa, 0x24, 0xc00000cd20)
        /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt/build.go:28 +0xa2
    github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt.(*Client).backup(0xc0000c0dc0, 0x207e0e0, 0xc0000b4010, 0x202af30, 0x6, 0x2071000, 0x28, 0xc000b03900, 0x418bfb)
        /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt/client.go:267 +0x4a
    github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt.(*Client).Open(0xc0000c0dc0, 0x207e0e0, 0xc0000b4010, 0x2082660, 0xc0000b9058, 0x202af30, 0x6, 0x2071000, 0x28, 0xc000b03a98, ...)
        /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt/client.go:107 +0x58a
    github.com/influxdata/chronograf/server.openService(0x207e0e0, 0xc0000b4010, 0x202af30, 0x6, 0x2071000, 0x28, 0xc0000462aa, 0x24, 0x2056de0, 0xc0003dffb0, ...)
        /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/chronograf/server/server.go:451 +0x143
    github.com/influxdata/chronograf/server.(*Server).Serve(0xc000095880, 0x207e0e0, 0xc0000b4010, 0x0, 0x0)
        /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/chronograf/server/server.go:343 +0x498
    main.main()
        /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/chronograf/cmd/chronograf/main.go:47 +0x1ec
```

Now, when I delete the chronograf deployment and files from the volume I got other errors.

```
panic: page 5 already freed

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/boltdb/bolt.(*freelist).free(0xc000710f60, 0x3, 0x7f1c06bd8000)
    /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/boltdb/bolt@v0.0.0-20160719165138-5cc10bbbc5c1/freelist.go:117 +0x2a6
github.com/boltdb/bolt.(*Tx).Commit(0xc000116620, 0x0, 0x0)
    /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/boltdb/bolt@v0.0.0-20160719165138-5cc10bbbc5c1/tx.go:176 +0x1b7
github.com/boltdb/bolt.(*DB).Update(0xc00000c1e0, 0xc000a8f790, 0x0, 0x0)
    /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/boltdb/bolt@v0.0.0-20160719165138-5cc10bbbc5c1/db.go:602 +0xe8
github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt.(*OrganizationsStore).CreateDefault(0xc0000b88b8, 0x207e0e0, 0xc0000b4010, 0x0, 0x0)
    /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt/organizations.go:55 +0x1b5
github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt.(*OrganizationsStore).Migrate(...)
    /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt/organizations.go:37
github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt.(*Client).migrate(0xc0002aa0a0, 0x207e0e0, 0xc0000b4010, 0x202af30, 0x6, 0x2071000, 0x28, 0x0, 0x0)
    /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt/client.go:186 +0x64
github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt.(*Client).Open(0xc0002aa0a0, 0x207e0e0, 0xc0000b4010, 0x2082660, 0xc0000b8120, 0x202af30, 0x6, 0x2071000, 0x28, 0xc000a8fa98, ...)
    /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/chronograf/bolt/client.go:116 +0x423
github.com/influxdata/chronograf/server.openService(0x207e0e0, 0xc0000b4010, 0x202af30, 0x6, 0x2071000, 0x28, 0xc0000462aa, 0x24, 0x2056de0, 0xc000710e70, ...)
    /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/chronograf/server/server.go:451 +0x143
github.com/influxdata/chronograf/server.(*Server).Serve(0xc00038a380, 0x207e0e0, 0xc0000b4010, 0x0, 0x0)
    /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/chronograf/server/server.go:343 +0x498
main.main()
    /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/chronograf/cmd/chronograf/main.go:47 +0x1ec
```

Config YAML files.

**Deployment:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: chronograf
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: chronograf
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: chronograf
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: wait-services
          image: busybox
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nslookup influx-svc.default.svc.cluster.local; do echo waiting service start; sleep 2; done;']
      containers:
        - name: chronograf
          image: chronograf:1.7.16
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8888
              name: http
          env:
            - name: "influxdb-url"
              value: "http://influx-svc:8086"
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/chronograf
              name: data
      volumes:
        - name: data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: chronograf-data
```

**Service:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: chronograf-dashboard
  labels:
    component: chronograf
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    component: chronograf
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: http
      targetPort: 8888
```

**Persistent Volume Claim:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: chronograf-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: storage-account
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the test, I found that the problem must caused by the property `mountOptions` of the storage class. I got the same error as you when I use the storage class example that AKS provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv#create-a-storage-class):

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azurefile
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000
  - mfsymlinks
  - nobrl
  - cache=none
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
```

And it would work perfectly when you delete the property `mountOptions` to let the storage class dynamically define itself. The storage class here:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azurefile
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
```

You can make more tests yourself if you really want to know which mount option is the problem. In addition, the persist volume of Azure disk would work well for you. Good luck!

Comment: it's weird because [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume#mount-options) uses that configuration, but well, it works without the options.